# MATLAB to C++ Programming Help Please

Tags: c++, matlab, porting, matlab-deployment

I have the MATLAB Code created but I am wondering if I can convert this MATLAB Code to C++ in a simplistic form.

```octave
%# Plotting T coordinates which represent the temperature 
%# in the vertical 

clear all; 

T=[22 24 16.2 8.4 -0.3 -7.3 -20.3 -37.1 -56.7]; 
H=[0 914 1876 3141 4267 5830 7530 9590 12280]; 
%# Plotting H coordinates which represent the height 
%# in the vertical 

%# 3 point running mean 
Tmean = conv(T, ones(1,3)/3); 
Tmean_valid = Tmean(3:end-2); 

Hmean = conv(H,ones(1,3)/3); 
Hmean_valid = Hmean(3:end-2); 

figure(1); 
plot(Tmean_valid,H(2:end-1), ':*r'); 
hold on 
plot(T,H,':*g') 
legend('Running Mean','Temperature Profile') 
title('Temperature Running Mean as function of height') 
xlabel('Temperature(C)') 
ylabel('Height (m)')"
```

Comment: That all depends on how good a C++ programmer you are. The calculation parts look simple enough, the plotting aspects less so.

Comment: You'll need a GUI (if you still want to keep the plotting), and a library that can do convolution / FFTs for you

Comment: That's what I was thinking Mathmatician1975. I been trying to come up with a C++ code for Convolution function. It's been quite difficult to find since they are no examples of it.

Comment: @nrhine1 How do I find info on that?

Comment: @RodMicael This is a discrete convolution so it is quite simple to implement (provided you know what discrete convolution is which I am guessing you do)

Comment: @mathematician1975 I have an idea of what it is but I found this code: for ( i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++ )
{
    y[i] = 0;                       // set to zero before sum
    for ( j = 0; j < kernelCount; j++ )
    {
        y[i] += x[i - j] * h[j];    // convolve: multiply and accumulate
    }
}

Comment: @mathematician1975: http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html

Comment: @SRK...well because the professor wanted to me to learn C++ coding just because these MATLAB functions may not behave what we would like them to behave.

Comment: @Sorry Oil Charlesworth....did know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MATLAB R13, you should have [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.fr/products/compiler/) 3.0, which is able to translate M code into C/C++ code. It's Windows only if I understood the documentation.

If you use the compiler, [this documentation page should help you](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html). For graphic views, I think the following command should work (not tested by myself): `mcc -B sgl mymainfile`.

I think you can also directly use the MCR (MATLAB Component Runtime) from C++, this runtime is a virtual machine capable of running M-code. I'm not sure, because I never did that ;)